# How do I test for the color of a pixel in my Java Applet?

Tags: java, applet, awt, java-2d

I have been doing some searching, and I have not found anything that suits my needs. I have a small game applet I am writing in Java. I am curious if there is a way for me to obtain the color value (preferably RGB format) of a pixel on the Applet Viewer screen. I am planning on using this to detect collisions. Is there a way to get the color values of a pixel on the Java Applet screen?

Comment: *"..get the color values of a pixel on the Java Applet screen?"*  Given your code presumably painted the colors, there has to be a better way to approach this.  1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a BufferedImage, with the width/height of your applet.
2. Create a Graphics2D object by calling [createGraphics()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#createGraphics%28%29) on your BufferedImage object.
3. Pass this Graphics2D object to the paint method of your applet - now the applet will be painted on your BufferedImage.
4. Call dispose() on your Graphics2D object.
5. Examine the pixel colors in your BufferedImage.

BTW, Andrew Thompson is probably right when he says that this must be an ineffective way of calculating collisions. Probably you should be looking into the [intersects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#intersects%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) method of Rectangle. Or for best results use a game engine, they have support for collision detection.